# Describe the symmetry group D of T of all rotations and reflections in R^2..

Tags: group-theory

Describe the symmetry group D of T of all rotations and reflections in $R^2$ as a subgroup of the symmetric group $\Sigma_5$. Where T is the regular pentagon (5-gon), with vertices enumerated clockwise by the numbers 1,2,3,4,5.

I understand the question and how to find the set. What i would like to know is, what is the significance of 'rotations and reflections in $R^2$'

Comment: Situate $T$ in ${\bf R}^2$. Then every symmetry of $T$ can be extended to a rotation or reflection in ${\bf R}^2.

Comment: Thank you. The simplicity of this question hit me just before you answered.